# subval_sort() is out of order

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have generated an array from a MySQL query which I then re-order using subval_sort(). This works fine except where the letter "E" figures in the ordering. In those cases, the value with the "E" in it comes out first. I have four instances of this happening, but everywhere else (this a very large site, btw) the ordering works fine.

Here is my array as it is generated from the db query:

```
Array ( 
[] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055070 [Size Code] => 7 [D Diameter] => 5/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 1/4" [L Length] => 3 1/4" ) 
[1] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055060 [Size Code] => 6 [D Diameter] => 1/2" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 7/32" [L Length] => 3" ) 
[2] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055050 [Size Code] => 5 [D Diameter] => 7/16" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 3/16" [L Length] => 2 3/4" ) 
[3] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055040 [Size Code] => 4 [D Diameter] => 5/16" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 1/8" [L Length] => 2 1/8" ) 
[4] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055030 [Size Code] => 3 [D Diameter] => 1/4" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 7/64" [L Length] => 2" ) 
[5] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055020 [Size Code] => 2 [D Diameter] => 3/16" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 5/64" [L Length] => 1 7/8" ) 
[6] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055010 [Size Code] => 1 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 3/64" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[7] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550E0 [Size Code] => 0 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 1/32" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[8] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055080 [Size Code] => 8 [D Diameter] => 3/4" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 5/16" [L Length] => 3 1/2" ) 
[9] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550D0 [Size Code] => 00 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => .025" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[10] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550C0 [Size Code] => 000 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => .020" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[11] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550B0 [Size Code] => 0000 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => .015" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[12] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550A0 [Size Code] => 00000 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => .010" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) )
```

I run this line:

`$productArray = subval_sort($productArray,'Item #');`

Then out comes this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550E0 [Size Code] => 0 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 1/32" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[1] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055010 [Size Code] => 1 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 3/64" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[2] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055020 [Size Code] => 2 [D Diameter] => 3/16" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 5/64" [L Length] => 1 7/8" ) 
[3] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055030 [Size Code] => 3 [D Diameter] => 1/4" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 7/64" [L Length] => 2" ) 
[4] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055040 [Size Code] => 4 [D Diameter] => 5/16" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 1/8" [L Length] => 2 1/8" ) 
[5] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055050 [Size Code] => 5 [D Diameter] => 7/16" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 3/16" [L Length] => 2 3/4" ) 
[6] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055060 [Size Code] => 6 [D Diameter] => 1/2" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 7/32" [L Length] => 3" ) 
[7] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055070 [Size Code] => 7 [D Diameter] => 5/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 1/4" [L Length] => 3 1/4" ) 
[8] => Array ( [Item #] => 091055080 [Size Code] => 8 [D Diameter] => 3/4" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => 5/16" [L Length] => 3 1/2" ) 
[9] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550A0 [Size Code] => 00000 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => .010" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[10] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550B0 [Size Code] => 0000 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => .015" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[11] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550C0 [Size Code] => 000 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => .020" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) 
[12] => Array ( [Item #] => 0910550D0 [Size Code] => 00 [D Diameter] => 1/8" [d Small Diameter (Pilot) ] => .025" [L Length] => 1 1/4" ) )
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does `subval_sort` come from? It's not a standard PHP function. Also, what number base is used for your `Item #` key? Is it simply hexadecimal?

Comment: Hi Phil - It's been a while since I did this, but I think I got it from here: http://www.firsttube.com/read/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-php/. But it never crossed my mind that it was not standard PHP. I'm not sure how to answer about the number base (I thought of that too). But I guess I have not reason to think it is not hexadecimal.

Comment: Well, it's your code so you should know where it's coming from. My guess is that whatever sort function is used under the covers is simply comparing strings

Comment: But if it is not standard PHP, why is it working at all?

Comment: You must have it defined somewhere. When you find it, add its implementation details to your question above

Answer (score 1):

maybe this modification of function from firsttube.com should work:

```
function subval_sort($a,$subkey,$sort_type="str") {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
                if($sort_type == "hex") {
                    $b[$k] = hexdec($v[$subkey]);
                } else {
                    $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
                }
    }
    asort($b);
    foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        $c[] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}


print_r($arr);
echo "<hr>";

$arr2 = subval_sort($arr, "Item #","hex");
print_r($arr2);
```

Comment: Thanx for the input steven - Actually, the problem was in the asort() function. Changing it to this resolved it: `asort($b,SORT_LOCALE_STRING);`